# Is it possible to remap UV objects and cause the underlying textures to be modified as well?

Tags: uv

A scenario we often run into at our studio is that we need to add/remove/change features of a model after it has been completed due to iteration or further alternatives of the model.

If, for example, we need to add a new limb to a creature - If the UV unwrap has no room for the new geometry we have to move or shrink a bunch of the other existing UV objects to fit it. When we have to do this we have to spend quite a lot of time rebaking and manually tweaking the existing textures to fit the changed locations of the existing UV objects. This is a big waste of time and it seems like something that should be automated via a tool surely?

The question is: Can Blender, or even any external tool, be used to take a UV object and move, rotate or scale it and also modify all underlying textures as well?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it's not possible. You have to make a new texture, reposition the images in Photoshop for example, in order to match the new UV. Daz3d has this tool, it's called TextureAtlas, and when you re-uv map the model, it also makes the needed modifications to the texture(s).